# simple sparql query not working, dates comparison

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I get "SR171: Transaction timed out" on the dbpedia sparql endpoint, for the following simple query: Why do I get this error? I don't set any timeout - it's on 0.

```
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbpedia2: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/>

PREFIX ont: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
SELECT ?name ?date (bif:substring(STR(?date), 1, 4) AS ?year) WHERE {
   ?person ont:birthDate ?date .
   ?person foaf:name ?name   

   . FILTER ( (fn:string-length(STR(?date)) = 10) && (bif:substring(STR(?date), 9, 2) = '05') && (bif:substring(STR(?date), 6, 2) = '02') && (?date > "1868-01-01"^^xsd:date) && (?date < "2005-01-01"^^xsd:date) )
```

Answer (score 8):

It's because your query is too hard for the DBPedia endpoint to answer without adversely impacting other users of the service.

As DBPedia is a well known public SPARQL endpoint it gets very heavily used so the people who host it have it configured to impose strict limits on how long a query can run for so that rogue users don't make the service unusable for others.

In your case your query will take a long time because you ask something that has a lot of initial results (592299 to be precise) and then apply a `FILTER` over it.  `FILTER` is quite expensive in SPARQL especially when doing string manipulation and date comparison.  AFAIK the DBPedia timeout is something fairly low like a few seconds and the endpoint simply cannot finish your query within that time because it takes too long to apply the `FILTER`.

*Note* - Here's the query I used to see how many results the first portion of your query was returning:

```
PREFIX ont: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>

SELECT COUNT(*) 
WHERE 
{
   ?person ont:birthDate ?date .
   ?person foaf:name ?name   
}
```

Comment: So there's nothing I can do. It works early in the morning and late at night. What is interesting is that it hardly takes 1-2 seconds for the query to execute and i see the error. So, it doesn't work at usual hours, when it should. Does it work from your system at usual hours?

Comment: This may depend on what timezone you are in and so when the peak usage is relative to your timezone.  I'm in the west coast of the US (PST) and just tried to run the query at 9am my time and it timed out

Comment: I am in Eastern Europe and it happens as i said above. This is not acceptable for a web application. I want to use the query in a PHP script with parameters ultimately. I understand this is a limitation of DB Pedia.Is there an option with DB Pedia to apply for a developer "KEY" like in other API's or some form of an agreement (even paid) which would increase the time for a query?